# How to create a horizontal-scrolling nav in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As can be demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmfcd3zt/), adding too many elements in a Bootstrap `.nav` causes it to just add items vertically down. How would I go about limiting its height and making it horizontally scrollable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First you need to tell the `ul` to not wrap and overflow into a scroll bar. Then the `li` elements need to not be floated and display inline. This will do it:

```
ul.nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmfcd3zt/8/

Comment: Perfect. In my case, where the `nav` was wrapped inside a `display: table` div I had to add `table-layout: fixed` to it and `width: 100%` to `ul.nav`.

Comment: How to use dropdown menus with `white-space: nowrap` ? Dropdown simply goes behind all elements, if you apply white-space property.

Comment: @AlexanderKim You expect help without even giving a vote for this answer? Anyway, asking questions like that should be done as a question, not a comment here.

Comment: @DavidG, could you, please, take a look at my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163551/dropdown-in-navbar-with-white-space-nowrap-bs4

Comment: @AlexanderKim That's Bootstrap 4, I've not done front end development for a while and have not used anything past v3.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. Is there any other ways to accomplish navbar with horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.nav{flex-wrap:nowrap;overflow-x:auto}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/l2ChB4vYmC) that I've found on a scrolling implementation of tabs.

Second, **I don't think that it's a good UX** to provide so many links in a tabbar. I recommend you to use dropdown menus or [mega menu](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/).

Comment: Ran into that. It doesn't implement actual *scrolling* though -- you can't get around having to click these arrows.