# Dropdown in navbar with white-space nowrap - BS4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Using `Vue-bootstrap` dropdown component: [b-nav-item-dropdown](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar#b-nav-item-dropdown)

I have an issue when using dropdown element in Navbar with horizontal scrolling when client has a small screen resolution.

**Code**

```
    <b-nav class="justify-content-end">
      <b-nav-item class="nav__map" active>First item</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item class="nav__help">Second item</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item-dropdown class="nav__city" text="New-York" extra-toggle-classes="nav-link-custom" right>
        <b-dropdown-item>New-York</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>San Francisco</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    </b-nav>
```

**CSS**

```
  .nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inherit;

    .nav-item {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
```

Because of `white-space: nowrap` when I click on a dropdown, that popup goes behind all elements:

[image]

I've tried to play with `z-index`, but had no success.

Comment: i tried your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr99nqk2qm) and i need your CSS to add it and see the issue

Comment: Here's the temporary link to the site on my pc

Comment: i don't understand